# Parsing big Affiliate XML feed hurting site's performance

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

My client requested that I implement an affiliate feed with which has the format of XML. However, the file is huge with 650k lines! I tried parsing it using a simpleXML, it worked, but it's extremely slow. As a result, the website sometimes does not load.

```
<?php
$html = "";
$url = "http://www.digitick.com/rss/distributeur/fluxAffiliation195_815.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
$title = $xml->content->eventList->event[$i]->eventName;
$link = $xml->content->eventList->event[$i]->eventUrl;
$description = $xml->content->eventList->event[$i]->eventPresentation;
$dateStart = $xml->content->eventList->event[$i]->dateStart;
$img = $xml->content->eventList->event[$i]->pictureUrl;

$html .= "<a href='$link'><h3>$title</h3></a>";
$html .= "<img src=$img>";
$html .= "$description";
$html .= "<br />$dateStart<hr />";
}
echo $html;
?>
```

What can I do to handle the this dynamic file (which updates every morning at 5am?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would import the file into a SQLite database file with a cron job. Then use SQL to request parts of it in your application. As an alternative cache the generated output and only read the large file once a day.